# Unable to run shell script with full permissions (UNIX)

Tags: php, bash, shell, unix

I have a shell script that is created inside a php script (given full permissions).  When I try to run the shell script from Terminal, I get no errors, but the script does not run (none of the commands execute).  Although, once I copy the contents of the shell script, paste them into a new file in XCode, and overwrite the old shell script, it runs properly.

Any suggestions?  I've been trying to figure this out for a very long time now with no progress.

I'm assuming that there is an issue with writing the shell script from the php script since it works when written in XCode or a text editor.

Here is the php script that writes the shell script:

```
<code>
    $filePath = "/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/php/Batch/modulator/Release23/Library/irShell.sh";
    $script = fopen($filePath, 'w+');
    chmod($filePath, 0777);
    fwrite($script,"#!/bin/sh");
    $irPath = "/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/php/Batch/modulator/Release23/Library"; //path to .ir files
    $modPath = "/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/php/Batch/modulator";

    if($dir = opendir($irPath)){        
        while(($file = readdir($dir)) !== false){
            $posA = strpos($file, ".IR");
            $posB = strpos($file, ".ir");
            $posC = strpos($file, ".Ir");
            if ($posA == true){
                $fileName = trim($file, ".IR");
                $noT = substr_replace($fileName, "", 0, 1);
                echo "$noT\n";
                fwrite($script, "\r" . $modPath . "/mod -o " . $irPath . "/codes/" . $noT . " " . $fileName . ".IR"); 
            }
            else if ($posB == true){
                $fileName = trim($file, ".ir");
                $noT = substr_replace($fileName, "", 0, 1);
                echo "$noT\n";
                fwrite($script, "\r" . $modPath . "/mod -o " . $irPath . "/codes/" . $noT . " " . $fileName . ".ir");
            }
            else if ($posC == true){
                $fileName = trim($file, ".Ir");
                $noT = substr_replace($fileName, "", 0, 1);
                echo "$noT\n";
                fwrite($script, "\r" . $modPath . "./mod -o " . $irPath . "/codes/" . $noT . " " . $fileName . ".Ir");
            }
        }
    }
</code>
```

And here's an example of a shell script that is generated by this php:

`#!/bin/sh`

```
/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/php/Batch/modulator/mod -o /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/php/Batch/modulator/Release23/Library/codes/1294 T1294.ir
/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/php/Batch/modulator/mod -o /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/php/Batch/modulator/Release23/Library/codes/1295 T1295.ir
/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/php/Batch/modulator/mod -o /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/php/Batch/modulator/Release23/Library/codes/1296 T1296.ir
```

Comment: Are the permissions of the written file still 777?

Comment: I'm a little suspicious of those `\r`.

Comment: Yes the permissions are still 777.

Comment: Try `\n`. Can you edit your answer to show an example of what the resulting script looks like? Please use @Dennis so users are automatically notified of replies

Comment: @Dennis sorry about that - just edited my post and added an example shell script that the php script created

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change all the `\r` in your `fwrite` statements to `\n` and move them to the end (or add a final `fwrite($script, "\n");` at the end right before you close the file (I don't see a `fclose()`, by the way).

```
fwrite($script,"#!/bin/sh" . "\n");
...
fwrite($script, $modPath . "/mod -o " . $irPath . "/codes/" . $noT . " " . $fileName . ".IR" . "\n");
...
fclose($script);
```

or

```
fwrite($script,"#!/bin/sh");
...
fwrite($script, "\n" . $modPath . "/mod -o " . $irPath . "/codes/" . $noT . " " . $fileName . ".IR" . "\n");
...
fwrite($script, "\n");
fclose($script);
```

Shell scripts should have newlines for line endings rather than carriage returns.

Comment: Thanks a lot Dennis that was it

Comment: The Carriage Return / Newline problem is so common, that there is a command to fix it: `dos2unix`